# Different XStream converters based on output media type

Tags: java, json, xstream

I've got a data structure that contains a mixed list of different types. I want to serialize/deserialize it with XStream so I wrote a converter that produces (and reads) the following output:

```
<list>
   <a foo="x"/>
   <b bar="y"/>
   <a foo="z"/>
</list>
```

Now this works beautifully while the output format is XML. But of course when the same converter is writing to a JSON stream, I get this:

```
 "list" : {
    "a" : [ { "@foo" : "x" }, {"@foo" : "z" } ],
    "b" : [ { "@bar" : "y" } ]
 ]
```

This isn't so beautiful because all `a`s and `b`s are grouped together, which is understandable but not what I want to see.

I could redesign the output to make it JSON-friendly but I don't want to change the XML representation.

How (if at all) is it possible with XStream to marshal/unmarshal objects differently based on the output format? The less intrusive the solution the better.

Comment: Are you using `JsonHierarchicalStreamDriver`? Have you tried `JettisonMappedXmlDriver`?  The former is documented as writing "optimized" JSON.

Comment: Could you provide your converter code ?

Comment: @ToYonos I'll post an MCVE as soon as I can.

Comment: Any news about the code ?